# Use grid item from adapter in dialog popup as view in Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-adapter

I want to set the view of popup dialog to be the grid item.
I get this item as view in OnClickListener event set in the adapter.

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View grid;
    final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_card, null);
        final TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.childName);
        //ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.childImage);
        textView.setText(children.get(position).getName());

        grid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setView(v);

                final Dialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
                final Handler handler  = new Handler();
                final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                };

                dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                    }
                });
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 3000);
            }
        });
    } else {
        grid = (View) convertView;
    }

    return grid;
}
```

I got these error:
"The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."

Comment: No one have an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Observations:
-Do not create redudant View Object when convertView is already available.
-Setting of data should be outside if-else loop.
-Click listener should also be outside if-else loop.
-Use ViewHolder pattern for initializing views.
-In child_card layout set Tag in xml for each textview and imageview.

For example

```
<TextView
android:id=""
android:layout_width =""
android:layout_height=""
android:tag="1"
/>
```

likewise for ImageView.

Try out below code.

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder;
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_card, null);
        holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.childName);
        //holder.imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.childImage);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    } 

    // set views here.
    holder.textView.setText(children.get(position).getName());

    // add click Listener here.
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setView(v);

                final Dialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
                final Handler handler  = new Handler();
                final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                };

                dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                    }
                });
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 3000);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
}

class ViewHolder {
    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me :(
I got the same error again